# An optimization problem for the minimum of three functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following function:

$$f(x,y) = \min \left\{ x(1-y), -1+2y+\frac{y^2}{4(1+y)}, \frac{1}{5} -\frac{11}{5}x \right\}$$

and I would like to optimize this function where

$$0 < x < \frac{1}{11}, \qquad \frac{2(\sqrt{10} - 1)}{9} < y < 1$$

How do I go about this? How do I find the maximum? If it helps, I am trying to understand page 156 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1415801554). I can't seem to get where the cubic polynomial comes into the picture? Thanks.

Comment: Had you try find the maximus of the three functions and compare them?

Comment: @Na'omi I understand that I could do it for the minima. But I am trying to find the maximum value of the minimum of the three functions? I didn't think your suggestion would work. Because let's say I found the maximum of the three, but then my function isn't choosing that value anyways?

Comment: You're right, it's more difficult that I was thinking.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think the paper has only  47 pages, maybe you linked other paper? I had an idea, maybe you could try to find the regions in which the minimun is this, that or the last function, so analyze in each of the three regions, but I have no time to test the idea. So, sorry if this not help. Good studies.